# Hurrying after her dog?

Tags: sentence-construction

*Source : Compact Advanced Student's Book*

*The woman hurried after her dog, calling to him to come back.*

I know that this sentence can be written as follows and can also be reversed.

*Calling to him to come back, the woman hurried after her dog*

or *The woman hurried after her dog and called to him to come back*

Well, can we write this sentence like this?

***Hurrying after her dog, the woman called to him to come back.*** ???

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it?

Comment: I'd prefer taking out the **to** him: 
"Hurrying after her dog, the woman called [to] him to come back."